# How to know the object's type? Javascript

Tags: javascript, request, request-cancelling

i have that print on my console.

[image]

[image]

I print this when my error function is called

```
export function handleRequestError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

When I do, error.cancel, it comes undefined. Would I be able to do some verification of this type? If cancel comes, I do something like that

```
    export function handleRequestError(error) {
          console.log(error);
          if(error['Cancel'] === undefined) return //doesnt work
   }
```

How do I check that "Cancel"?

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste the key value, including the underscores?

Comment: Maybe you want to do `if (error.Cancel.message === undefined)`.  error.Cancel always seems to be an object (ie, defined).  Or perhaps error.message === undefined?

Comment: yep. Undefined. Cancel is not a key. But i dont know what "cancel" is

Answer (score 0):

In the prototype, you can see that the property `__CANCEL__` is set to true.

Do this:

```
export function handleRequestError(error) {
  console.log(error);
  if(error['__CANCEL__'] === undefined) return;
}
```